# Swift - Sorting with mutiple object types, multi-dimensional array, changeable order

Tags: swift

I am trying to sort an array multiple records containing strings, dates and other numbers.  I want to be able to have up to 4 columns sorted based on 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th choices with an ascending/descending option. Based on other examples I am able to accomplish this objective, but only for sorting as a string.

The code will sort the string array, but since some strings are numbers and dates, the sort is not as desired.  I would like to use the .localizedStandardComare method for sorting, but I don't know how to incorporate it into this code for the array.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class MyViewController : UIViewController {

var array = [["a","e","def","ttt","",""],["z","2019/5/28","ccc","123",""], ["z","2019/10/23","def","567",""]]
// Constants below are assigned based on optional ascending/descending choice
let a1 = 4  // dummy column
let a2 = 0  // descending order for column 0
let b1 = 1  // ascending order for column 1
let b2 = 4  // dummy column
let sorted = array.sorted(by: {($0[a1],$1[a2],$0[b1],$1[b2]) < ($1[a1],$0[a2],$1[b1],$0[b2])})
print("sorted array=", sorted)

// The results below show that columns 0 and 1 are sorted correctly as strings, but column 1 needs to be sorted as date similar to what this closure would achieve for a simpler array
// --> {$0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == orderedAscending}

sorted array= [["z", "2019/10/23", "def", "567", ""], ["z", "2019/5/28", "ccc", "123", ""], ["a", "e", "def", "ttt", "", ""]]
```

Comment: Start by using an array of struct. That will make things so much easier.

Comment: Just for clarification, are you saying that it is not possible to apply the "localizedStandardCompare" function to the "sorted" method statement in the code I have? If so, thats too bad. The one liner was so simple, does multi-colum sort but only can use default comparison.

Comment: I have used the struct for sorting as shown in answer below. However I am not able to make the choice of sort a variable so that sort statements can be based on the user choice. It would be nice to make one sort statement like $x.choice1 < $y.choice1 where could be x, y, and choice1 could be variables changed based on user input.  Is there anyway to declare these variables? If not, lots of redundant if statements for a large colunm array.

Answer (score 0):

New working code written with array of struct is below.  More code, but I suspect could be written more efficiently:

```
var array = [["asdf","45","10/3/2019","100.34",""],["asdf","100","6/12/2019","12.3",""],["asdf","10","12/16/2019","5.67",""],["asdf2","450","4/3/2019","923",""],["asdf3","9","5/20/2019","567",""]]

struct arrayStruct {
    var stringV : String!
    var intV : Int!
    var dateV : Date!
    var costV : Float!
    var stringD : String!
}
var newArray = [arrayStruct]()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
for i in 0 ..< array.count {
        let rowArray = array[i]
        let rowInt = Int(rowArray[1])
        let rowDate = dateFormatter.date(from: rowArray[2])
        let rowCost = Float(rowArray[3])
        newArray.append(arrayStruct(stringV: rowArray[0], intV: rowInt!, dateV: rowDate!, costV: rowCost!, stringD: rowArray[4]))
        }
newArray.sort(by: {($0.stringV, $0.dateV) < ($1.stringV, $1.dateV)})
    print("New Sorted Array:")
    for i in 0 ..< newArray.count {
        print("col0=",newArray[i].stringV!, " col2=",newArray[i].dateV!)
    }

Result: 
New Sorted Array:
col0= asdf  col2= 2019-06-12 04:00:00 +0000
col0= asdf  col2= 2019-10-03 04:00:00 +0000
col0= asdf  col2= 2019-12-16 05:00:00 +0000
col0= asdf2  col2= 2019-04-03 04:00:00 +0000
col0= asdf3  col2= 2019-05-20 04:00:00 +0000
```